# Solidity - Remix - 0.7.1 - VM error: invalid opcode when I'ḿ trying to initialize ztruct containing a (nested) mapping

Tags: solidity, remix

I could compile the code above, but when I call createRequest function, I got an error:

The code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.7.1;

contract Campaign {
    struct Request {
        uint value;
        mapping(address => bool) approvals;
    }

    Request[] public requests;
    address public manager;
    uint public minimumContribution;
    uint public numRequests;

    constructor(uint minimum) {
        manager = msg.sender;
        minimumContribution = minimum;
    }

    function contribute() public payable {
        require(msg.value > minimumContribution);
    }

    function createRequest(uint value) public returns (uint requestId) {
        requestId = numRequests++;
        Request storage r = requests[requestId];
        r.value = value;
        r.approvals[msg.sender] = true;
    }
}
```

The error when I call createRequest function on the Campaign contract deployed on Remix JavaScript VM environment:

```
transact to Campaign.createRequest errored: VM error: invalid opcode. invalid opcode The execution might have thrown. Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

I tried to write a code similar of the documentation (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.0/types.html#structs), but I couldn't understand why I got this error.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Where do you ever `push` anything to the `requests` array???

Comment: You cannot access `requests[requestId]` without doing so.

Comment: Ok. I got your point. But I can't create a Request variable in memory to push to array. I realized the 0.6.2 and 0.7.1 documentation sample code don't use array, but a mapping. I will try this approach. Thanks @goodvibration